# Trigger is not firing when clicking on element in GTM

Tags: triggers, element, google-tag-manager

i have configured a click trigger with a matched css-selectior.

Unfortunately, trigger is not fired because GTM is not seeing any matches, however, in screenshot you can see the. Can anyone help out, please? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzgcL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wildcard CSS Selector.
Instead of "li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble" use "li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble,li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble *"

Comment: Hey Ramon, unfortunately, it did not worked with li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble,li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble *

Comment: "li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble, li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble *"
Sorry, forgot an escape.
This should definitly work....

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working: li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble, li.swiper-silde.collection-bubble * Did you mean space?